# Triangle in asterisks in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, geometry

I am trying to make scalable triangle out of asterisks and I've got this code which is completely functional and all and resizes the right way but it doesn't output the 3rd side of the triangle. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner a;
        a = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Scalable Triangle program!");
        System.out.print("What size triangle do you want?");
        int size = a.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++)
          System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println("*");
        //top line
        for (int j = 1; j < (size - 1); j++)
        {
          for (int k = 0; k < (size - 1 - j); k++)
          System.out.print(" ");
          System.out.println("*");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++)
           System.out.print("* ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        //bottom line
      }
    }
```

I would like it to output this if I answer the question with, for example, a 7:

```
          *
         * *
        *   *
       *     *  
      *       *
     *         *
    * * * * * * *
```

Right now it would output this:

```
      *
     * 
    *   
   *       
  *       
 *         
* * * * * * *
```

Comment: Which side is the 3rd side, and have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: What have you done to debug your code?

Comment: Though you may not need the extra brackets, it's better practice to always use them

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had a quick look and the reason why it's not printing the 3rd side is because you don't have the code to print it.

The bit you want to look at is in the nested loop (the second j counter that you're using). At the moment, the nested loop (the one using the k counter) is outputting the spaces before the x's below.

```
      *
     x 
    x   
   x       
  x       
 x         
* * * * * * *
```

What you want to do is change the

```
System.out.println("*");
```

in that loop to not start a new line.

Then add another loop after that to add the spaces and asterisks. For this asterisk you'll want to output it as a new line.

Since this looks like a homework task, I won't give you any code to do it. This should hopefully be enough information to help you figure it out. Remember, always trace through your code 1 line at a time so you know what it's doing.

Also, be careful of any extra spaces that you might be adding. If this is a homework task, you'll want the output to match the provided output perfectly.

Good luck.

Comment: "the reason why it's not printing the 3rd side is because you don't have the code to print it." I'm deeply conflicted about whether I should laugh at this... But +1 for good hints and not giving code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get some mathematical relations between line numbers, number of spaces, number of stars etc. as shown below:

Line number : Number of spaces after 1st star.

```
      *
    1* *1
   2*   *3
  3*     *5  
 4*       *7
5*         *9
* * * * * * *
```

If the number of spaces after 1st star = x and the line number = y. Then
x = 2y-1

The code:

```
public class Dia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(drawTriangle("*", 7));

    }// main

    // Assume equilateral triangle
    public static String drawTriangle(String symbol, int side) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int i = 0;

        //Top line
        for(i = 1; i < side; i++){sb.append(" ");}
        sb.append(symbol);
        sb.append("\n");

        for(i = 1; i < side-1; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < side-i; j++){sb.append(" ");}
            sb.append(symbol);

            for(int k = 1; k <= (i * 2)- 1 ; k++){sb.append(" ");}
            sb.append(symbol);
            sb.append("\n");

        }

        //Bottom line
        for(i = 0; i < side; i++){sb.append(symbol + " ");}

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Triangle {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner a;
    a = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Scalable Triangle program!");
    System.out.print("What size triangle do you want?");
    int size = a.nextInt();
    for (int j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++)
      System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println("*");
    //top line
    for (int j = 1; j < (size - 1); j++)
    {
      for (int k = 0; k < (size - 1 - j); k++)
      System.out.print(" ");
      System.out.print("*");
      for (int m = 0; m < 2*j-1; m++){
              System.out.print(" ");
        }
       System.out.println("*");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++)
       System.out.print("* ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    //bottom line
  }
}
```